# Differentiate between null and default in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, null, default

I have a method which supports all kinds of types and there I want to check if the value is null but only for reference types, for value types such check does not make sense.
Since this method is deep in the call tree it would be complicated to just duplicate the method for reference types and use class constraint there.

```
void Foo<T>(T a)
{
   // check for null for reference types only
   if (a == null) 
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: The code that you have written correctly does what you want. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: ... or are you concerned about nullable value types?

Comment: @canton7: well, he said that he wants this check only for reference types. For example nullable types could be null but aren't reference types. `Type.IsValueType` handles that as shown in my answer.

Comment: OP doesn't actually say that -- they say "for value types such check does not make sense", which doesn't consider nullable value types at all. Hence my question.

Comment: *"for value types this does not make sense"* - I beg to differ, `int?` is a value type and can be null. I think this is a bit of an XY problem here, or maybe a code smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Type.IsValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-DE/dotnet/api/system.type.isvaluetype?view=xamarinmac-3.0) if you want to "check for null for reference types only":

```
void Foo<T>(T a)
{
    bool isReferenceType = !typeof(T).IsValueType;
    if (isReferenceType && a == null)
    {
    }
}
```

So nullable types(which are structs, hence value types) will not pass this check even if `a == null` would return `true`. I guess this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

If `T` is a value type (and is not a nullable value type, such as `int?`), then the test `a == null` is still perfectly valid: the test `a == null` can never be `true` and the whole `if` statement will be optimized away by the runtime.

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIGYACMhgYQYG8aHuGBtAZQAW2KAAcAMtmAA6AEoBXAHYYAlvhjSAUiowBxGIphQVYABQYAnqJgQAZqZXKAlE4C6XHsRQMAYhAgAPAAqAHymQQzYTh7cnNQ8CQwqtgym2AwAvBkMivIANnnR8YmxMSWe5ACcpgBEAHL5eTVOANxlCQC+ZV3UPTRAA==).

If `T` is a nullable value type, then the test `a == null` will still match when `a`'s value is `null` (e.g. `Foo<int?>(null)`).

If `T` can be a nullable value type and you do not want to enter the `if` if `a` is `null`, then [Tim Schmelter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76712053/1086121) does what you want, but will be a little inefficient (although the next .NET version will improve that significantly).